# My rest assured(java) code is throwing me a 308-permanent redirect but it is giving valid response in postman and other libs like requests lib(python)

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, endpoint

My rest assured(java) code is throwing me a 308-permanent redirect but it is giving valid response in postman and other libs like requests lib(python)

`   RestAssured.baseURI="https://live-rates.freightify.com/instantqbt/command/Spotrates";

```
RequestSpecification contentType = RestAssured.given()
        .header("Content-Type","application/json")
        .header("X-Block","true")
        .header("X-RequestID","test-rest-assured1")
        .body("{\r\n"
                + "    \"origin_port\": \"deham\",\r\n"
                + "    \"destination_port\": \"aejea\",\r\n"
                + "    \"cargo_ready_date\": \"2023-04-17\",\r\n"
                + "    \"load_type\": \"20GP\",\r\n"
                + "    \"quantity\": 8,\r\n"
                + "    \"cargo_weight\": 144,\r\n"
                + "    \"vendor_id\": \"2081\",\r\n"
                + "    \"sub_vendor\": \"msc\"\r\n"
                + "}").log().all();

Response response = contentType.post();

response.then().log().all();`
```

Comment: Probably Postman automatically follows redirects, and your code does not. Check if your library has an option to enable that or handle the situation yourself. (Nit: it's probably not throwing an exception, so don't overuse the term throwing just because you get something you didn't expect.)